# Source and destination ports are different, so which port number i need to mention in inbound aws security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

In the port range option of aws inbound/outbound security groups weather we need to mention sourceip port or else destinationip port.

Q1: For example PROD is trying to connect GATEWAY in this case in the gateway inbound security group weather I need to mention the PROD  port or else GATEWAY port in the port range column.
And in return GATEWAY is trying to connect PROD then in Gateway outbound security group weather I need to mention the PROD  port or else GATEWAY port in the port range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining rules, use the port number associated with the **destination**. For example:

- `Laptop` connects to `EC2-Instance`
- Security Group on `EC2-Instance` permits **inbound** connections on port 80

It does not matter which port is used as the 'source' port on `Laptop`. The security group only looks at the *destination port*.

Another example:

- `EC2-Instance` connects to `www.example.com` on the Internet
- Security Group on `EC2-Instance` permits **outbound** connections on port 80

It does not matter which port is used as the 'source' port on the `EC2-Instance`.

**Security Groups** in AWS Virtual Private Clouds (VPCs) are [stateful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53625507/174777). This means that if traffic is allow 'in', then it is also allowed 'out'. So there is no need to define *Outbound* rules just to respond to *Incoming* connections. Responses will be automatically permitted purely as a result of having *Inbound* rules accept the incoming traffic.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply .Is that you are telling like I need to mention only the port of my ec2 and not to bother the guest ec2 port . For example if guest ec2 10.x.y.z(port:80) is trying to connect my ec2 10.1.2.3(port:51406) . Then in this case I need to mention the portrange(51406) source(10.x.y.z) in my ec2 inbound security group. And in the outbound my ec2(port: 9011) is trying to connect to 10.5.6.7(port:443) in this case in outbound rule of my ec2 should I need to mention portrange(9011) destination (10.5.6.7) this is what I understood. Can you correct me if was wrongly understand

Comment: No, it is always the _destination_ port. So in your first example, it would need to permit inbound on port 51406. And in the second example, it would need to permit outbound port 443. Also FYI, port 80 will _never_ be used as a 'source' port from a system -- it will always be a high number (I think 49152 to 65535). The 'source' ports are randomly generated for the session and will never feature in the Security Group rules.

Comment: Thanks John for  clarification. Now I got the point. either I had chosen the CIDR RANGE or individual ip or Another security group I'd as source  in all these case should I need to choose the  destination port only.

Comment: Yes. The destination port has a presumed **protocol** (eg port 22 = SSH, port 80 = HTTP), which is mostly the intention of creating rules.